# How to use GradCAM for text classification with 1D CNN

Tags: nlp, conv-neural-network, text-classification, xai

I am conducting text classification using a 1D CNN, and I am unsure of how to apply Grad-CAM or any other XAI method to interpret the results. Most resources I've encountered focus on applying these techniques to image classification tasks.
Any suggestions or assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

i have tried the code in the notebook provided here [How to use GradCAM for multichannel 1D CNN models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72462089/how-to-use-gradcam-for-multichannel-1d-cnn-models). but the results wasn't what i was looking for i couldn't get feature importance for each word